# Jenkins goes out of heap (OutOfMemoryError) when the tests print a lot of log messages to System.out

Tags: java, jenkins

I am using Jenkins to run some system tests.
Those tests write 18-20 MB printouts to the standard output.
Jenkins job is configured to run with 2048 MB max heap size.
Strangely enough, when these printouts are turned on, jenkins goes OutOfMemoryError (out of heap space).

It is definitely the printouts which cause the problem. Without them, all works fine.
What troubles me, how 20 MB of text cause the whole process to be OutOfMemory.

I already have increased the heap size from 1 GB to 2 GB, but without any result.
Without the prints, on 1GB max heap size all tests work fine.

Here the exception:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2786)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:94)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:430)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.TeeStream.write(TeeStream.java:44)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:430)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.TeeStream.write(TeeStream.java:42)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:430)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.TeeStream.write(TeeStream.java:42)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:430)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.TeeStream.write(TeeStream.java:42)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:430)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.TeeStream.write(TeeStream.java:42)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:430)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.TeeStream.write(TeeStream.java:42)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:430)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.TeeStream.write(TeeStream.java:42)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:202)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:263)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:106)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:190)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:111)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:476)
    at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:619)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:756)
    ...
```

Does anyone know some sort of configuration of Jenkins, that a lot of prints to the System.out (20 MB of them) won't cause the OutOfMemory to occur?

Clarification: I don't want to debug Jenkins, I am not a Jenkins developer. I use Jenkins to run system tests using JUnit on my application as CI.

Comment: Try looking at the Jenkins process with a profiler (or at least `jvisualvm`). It should show you the objects that eat up the memory, and the methods that are invoked too many times. Also, the stack trace suggests that the output is written to at least 7 streams - if somehow it means that 7 copies of the data are stored in memory, this can somewhat explain the memory problems.

Comment: Of course you are right to analyze the memory, but in my code I simply put the following line: System.out.println("blabla"); Analyzing the memory won't give me much, since I didn't write Jenkins. I simply use it to test my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try starting jenkins with "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" JVM argument, that should give you a dump file to analyze whenever you get the out of memory exception.

EDIT --

I think I may have something for you.
First of, the surefire plugin by default forks a new JVM for running tests, and this JVM does not inherit JVM properties of the maven JVM, i.e. if you've set the maven process to have 2048MB Max Heap, it will not be set for the JVM forked by the surefire plugin.
So for setting JVM args of the forked JVM, use the 'argLine' property of the surefire plugin. That way you'll be able to set the Max heap for the forked JVM and not the maven JVM.

Secondly,  It looks like the surefire plugin redirects the stdout/stderr and keeps the contents of stuff written to these 2 streams in memory, that's why you may be running out of memory.
So you can also try setting 'redirectTestOutputToFile' property to 'true', that way all sdtout goes to a file, may be that will avoid storing the stream contents in memory,
Or try setting the forkmode='always', that way it will fork one JVM per test-class, keeping the memory consumption from piling up, one test after another.

Hope one of these helps you in your issue.

Comment: But what will it give me? I know that my prints cause the problem. This occurs only with Jenkins. When running the same tests on development environment with eclipse, no problem occurs. So the memory dump will help me to debug Jenkins, but I am not there. I asked this question here, is whether someone know some sort of configuration of Jenkins, that 20 MB of additional prints to System.out won't blow it away on OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: I know this will not help your directly, but you can then take this dump file to jenkins devs and may be it will have something that they can look at and probably fix in Jenkins. That's how an open source project works, can't fix stuff unless users report back bug reports, can they ?

Comment: You are totally right, but I don't want to file a defect to Jenkins just yet, before I will get to bottom of this, whether it is a known problem.

Comment: hey, I edited my comments to add some options that you can try setting on the surefire plugin, to help you get around the memory issue.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Also the problem was, that in 2 different pom.xml there was "argLine" property. So, at first I changed in the root pom.xml, but it was not affected, then I searched all the pom.xml in my project, and I saw, that there was some child pom.xml which also had this propery, and overrided mine, which was set in the root pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

The OutOfMemoryError is caused by too much printed output of your test cases.
I had the same issue, where a single test seemed to print too much.

I don't know whether the same effect happens when several tests are fine for themselves but produce too much output overall when executed together. But I would guess that memory is freed after each test.

### Analysis

My heapdump analysis had shown that the class in question `TeeStream` seems to fork an output to two streams (thus the "T"). I had a hierachy of `TeeStreams`, referencing each other while also holding an own `Printer`. Your stacktrace also indicates the same.
That means each output coming in is propagated through this hierachy and printed several times. Thus the size of the printers increased dramatically the lower in the hierachy they were. This is very leaky of course and explains the high memory consumption.

To me this seems to be a bug in Surefire.

### Handy workaround

As a workaround I **reduced the printed output of my tests.**

### More sustainable solutions

If this is no option for you, you should configure Surefire (in your .pom) to run in forked mode. I'm sure passing Xmx as an argument to increase the heap size is also possible there.

Answer (score 0):

there is some very much memory consuming analysis of the output, scanning for errrors and warnings -  disable it

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your answer

Comment: @goryachev: I mean: there is an (more or less default) Post "Task" (or what ever it is called) for the Hudson/Jerkins projects. That task scan the log files, and it is very memmory consuming.